# Opencv IP Camera Error

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio, opencv, c++-cli

I am using andriod app (IP webcam) as ip camera.
i'm running below code in separate thread. because if i run in main thread it crashes the program.

```
VideoCapture cap; Mat img;
cap.open("http://192.168.0.101:8080/video?x.mjpeg");
while(waitKey(33)!=27)
{
    try{
        cap>>img;
        cout<<"Thread active"<<endl;
        if(img.empty())
        {
         cout<<"camera Closed"<<endl;
         break;
        }
         imshow("Video",img);
      } catch(...{}    
}
```

everything works fine. even if i turn off camera(close andriod app) it prints "Camera closed" in Console.
The problem occurs when i turn off wifi on my andriod device. 
the moment i turn off wifi directly(having app still running) thread freezes, even though its in try catch block!

i have a button_click event in my form and i'm calling`cap.release();`  in it.
if i click this button then, follow error is displayed in visual studio (no error from opencv)

> HEAP[Test.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 6797780 modified at
>   67977d4 after it was freed Windows has triggered a breakpoint in
>   Test.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   Test.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Test.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

Have anybody come across this error?
Visual Studio debugger stops at `cap.release();`  line 
Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Thanks & Regards

P.S: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with opencv 3.0 [C++/Cli (winforms)]

**Update:** i added `thread->Abort();` in button_clickEvent (replacing `cap.release();`). Program also crash for thread->Abort();
is there a safer way to terminate thread?
I think this is a bug in OpenCV, is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do a call *cap.release()*, it will be called the second time when *cap*'s visibility zone is ended.
It also will be great to check *cap.isOpened()* before reading.

"thread->Abort();" I suppose it's ok, another way to stop is set up static global flag to finish the loop, like:

```
static char doCapThread = 1;
...
   while((waitKey(33)!=27) && doCapThread) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer theg4sh,  
it will still crash even if i remove 'cap.release();'  please refer to **Update:**  section in above question. Thanks